In HybridCache .net 9.0 is there an easy way to ignore null values in the serialized Json value?
I'm using HybridCache in .net 9.0 and I want to leave out the object properties that have a null value.
code:
services.AddHybridCache(options =>
{
    options.MaximumPayloadBytes = 1024 * 1024;
    options.MaximumKeyLength = 1024;
    options.DefaultEntryOptions = new HybridCacheEntryOptions
    {                
        Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(7),
        LocalCacheExpiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(7)
    };
});

Is there an easy way to get this done? Like in:
services.AddControllersWithViews()
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});

